# ng-click in directive seems to trigger only once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I am trying to implement a directive that replace a  tag by a  with ng-click in it. 
The ng-click call a function that replace the content of a div (always the same) with the content of another element,  the id of which is passed as parameter.
I managed to make it work, but only for the first click. After that, the page is reloaded and it seems that it is because ng-click isn't triggered, but the (empty) href attribute is.

the html code :

```
  <!-- language: lang-html -->
  <div id="uiMain" class="container">
    Go to <go target="block01">01</go>, <go target="block02">02</go> or <go target="block03">03</go>
  </div>
  <div id="block01" class="block">
    Go to <go target="block02">02</go> or <go target="block03">03</go>
  </div>
  <div id="block02" class="block">
    Go to <go target="block01">01</go> or <go target="block03">03</go>
  </div>
  <div id="block03" class="block">
    Go to <go target="block01">01</go> or <go target="block02">02</go>
  </div>
```

and my directive :

```
.directive('go', function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            target: "@"
        },
        transclude: true,
        template: '<a href="" ng-click="displayBlock(\'{target}\')"><ng-transclude></ng-transclude></a>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.displayBlock = function() {
                // Get the content of the target block
                var content = angular.element(document.querySelector("#"+attrs.target));
                // Get the main container
                var mainContainer = angular.element(document.querySelector("#uiMain"));
                // then replace the link with it
                if (content !== null) { 
                    //mainContainer.html($compile(content.innerHTML)($scope)); 
                    mainContainer.html(content.html()); 
                }
            };
        }
    };
});
```

I have tried putting my function back into the controller but he behavior is the same. 
I also tried to use $compile or $apply to make sure that the scope is up to date with the pasted html content : this doesn't work because the directives in my target block were already compiled.

Here is my [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/aOMQdpmOSP95KuTrkAkC?p=preview) for the whole code.

I want to be able to click the links to go back and forth, but for now there is something that stop the ng-click from firing more than once.

---

EDIT:
thanks to Mosh-Feu, i managed to make it work by adding `ng-non-bindable` to all target element and changing my directive as follow :

```
.directive('go', function($compile) {
return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: true,
    transclude: true,
    template: '<a href="" ng-click="displayBlock(\'{target}\')"><ng-transclude></ng-transclude></a>',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.displayBlock = function() {
            // Get the content of the target block
            var content = angular.element(document.querySelector("#"+attrs.target));
            // Get the main container
            var mainContainer = angular.element(document.querySelector("#uiMain"));
            // then replace the link with it
            if (content != null) { 
                mainContainer.html(content.html()); 
                $compile(mainContainer)(scope);
            };
        };
    }
};
```

});

But Aditya Bhave solution is cleaner, so I will be using it. Thanks a lots guys !

Comment: That's because that once you call `mainContainer.html(content.html());` the html now not "attached" to angular so angular is not "listening" to the click. I see that you tried with `$compile` but you pass to it `content.innerHTML` which is not the template you want (e.g. `Go to <go target="block02">02</go> or <go target="block03">03</go>`) but the actual html.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tried to put a `ng-non-bindable` directive in the target elements and then compile the `innerHTML` but I run into others problems : either the `$compile' return an undefined object, or i got a `[jqLite:nosel]` error from angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is, when we replace innerHTML of div with html(), it does not compile it as an angularjs code. The correct way is to use ng-templates.

Take a look at this Plunkr - http://next.plnkr.co/edit/x0TiUkka5nJwqB8K

1. I am using a div with ng-include attribute set to mainBlock.html template initially.
2. On Click event is changing the template URL of the parent controller.

Note - We can have more cleaner code, if we pass temmplateURL as a attribute to directive and then change it in onclick instead of using scope.$parent.